# How do I allow core dump in a spark executor?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to debug an application, I tried setting ulimit -c unlimited on all my nodes in the cluster. However I still see the message that core dump is disabled. How do I enable core dumps?